# "hg add" of tortoisehg 2.7.1 does not work

Tags: tortoisehg, bitbucket

I tried both in my laptop and PC (OS is Win7 Enterprise x64), none of them work.

The test process is quite simple:

1. Apply an account in bitbucket
2. Create a private repository named "test"
3. Download "tortoisehg-2.7.1-hg-2.5.2-x64.msi" and install it (not change any default setting in installing)
4. Create a local folder, run command "hg clone htts:.....", the clone is finished successfully
5. Configure UserPofile\mercurial.ini, add below section

   [ui]

   username = xxx xxxemail
6. Create a test file "foo.foo" with content "foo" string in "test" folder
7. Run command "hg stat", get output "? foo.foo"
8. Run command "hg add", get output "adding foo.foo"
9. Run command "hg stat", get output "? foo.foo"
10. Run command "hg commit -m "test"", get output "nothing changed"
11. Run command "hg log", output nothing

I don't know why in step 9 I still get "? foo.foo" instead of "A foo.foo", does anybody encounter similar issue?

Another strange thing is in my PC the first added file can be added/committed/putted successfully, then I can never add file again, even if I remove the current repository and create a new one

I spent two days to find the root issue but it seems rare people encounter this issue. Could anybody give me a hand? Thanks in advance!

Comment: FixUtf8Extension caused this issue, the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540247/unicode-filenames-on-windows-mercurial-2-5-or-future said the same question as me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see problem

- on x86-build
- XP box
- on the same version of TortoiseHG

`hg init` repo have the same effect for adding file as clone, BTW

```
>hg stat
? .hgignore
? file.txt

>hg add
adding .hgignore
adding file.txt

z:\test>hg status
A .hgignore
A file.txt

>hg commit -m "initial data"

>hg log
changeset:   0:3cc2ddcb0417
tag:         tip
user:        I
date:        Fri Mar 08 17:47:56 2013 +0600
summary:     initial data
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, that's my fault, for using unicode characters, I downloaded a plugin:  


   hg clone https://bitbucket.org/tinyfish/hg-fixutf8


and copied it to installation folder of tortoisehg, then added below lines in mercurial.ini:


  [extensions]
  fixutf8 = C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg-fixutf8\fixutf8.py


After removing this plugin, my tortoisehg works well again, but I can't work with my unicode files now. I don't know if this plugin has some bug or is incompatible with the newest tortoisehg

Comment: @Wait4amigo - "can't work" is bad description of problem. You can't work with Mercurial and Unicode filenames in repo only if you have to use repo in different OSes (Windows+(Linux|Mac). If your hg-clients are single-platform'ed - you don't have to worry about filenames

Comment: Thanks Lazy, yes the unicode file name now works after having modified some configuration.

Comment: @Wait4amigo - Would you be so generous to share this configuration changes with other HG users? I'm hitting my head against the wall for many months for finding _any_ VCS at all with cross-platform Unicode filenames support and still desperately hoping for HG / Tortoise finally be the first solving this problem...